# How do I find the coordinates of the lower red line

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

[image]

I'm trying to find the coordinates of the lower red line with `opencv_python`.

I already find the contours and all coordinates of this red line. but I only need the coordinates of the lower red line, not the red line above the enclosed grey region.

```py
def find_drawContours(path):                        
   src = cv2.imread(path)                          
   # cv2.imshow('input', src)                      
   src = cv2.GaussianBlur(src, (3,3), 0)           
   # cv2.imshow('', src)                           
   gray = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)    
   ret, binary = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.TH
   # cv2.imshow('binary', binary)                  

   image, contours, hierachy = cv2.findContours(bin
   for i in range(len(contours)):                  
       mm = cv2.moments(contours[i])               
       m00 = mm['m00']                             
       m10 = mm['m10']                             
       m01 = mm['m01']                             
       cx = np.int(m10/m00)                        
       cy = np.int(m01/m00)                        
       (x, y), (a, b), degree = cv2.fitEllipse(cont
       cv2.circle(src, (cx, cy), 2, (0,0,255), -1, 
       cv2.drawContours(src, contours, i, (0, 0, 25
   pix_list = []                                   
   for i in range(len(contours[0])):               
       a = contours[0][i]                          
       pix_list.append(a[0])                       
   pix_array = np.array(pix_list)                  
   print(min(pix_array[...,0]))                    
   # cv2.imwrite('img/res.contour.jpg',src)
```

[image]

Comment: Your question asks for coordinates of red line and description asks for white line. Which do you want? It looks like you're drawing the contour, why can't you use the coordinates of the contour? Is that not what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  I want coordinates of the red line below. I already find all coordinates of this red line, but I only want the coordinates of the red line below, not the red line above.

Answer (score 1):

I see a stray red dot on the image, and for the following technique to work, I would remove that using dilation and erosion operations. After this cleanup, I would:

1. Scan along every column (x-axis), and if there are **only two red colored points** on that column, find the point with the higher y-coordinate and add it to a list `points_on_lower_line[]`.
2. Once you have scanned all the columns of the image, `points_on_lower_line` will have  all the points that belong to the lower red line. You can further clean this up by making sure all the points are 4-connected.

Since you already store the contour points, you don't even have to draw the contour and scan the image for red pixels. you can sort the contour list by the x-coordinate of the points and filter the list by checking if only two points have the same x-coordinate and storing the lower point (higher y-coordinate). The resulting list will contain the points of the lower red line.

You could also use sets to avoid sorting the contour points:

```
contour_points[] #list of contour points
lower_line_point_list[] #list of points belonging to the lower red line

#get list of sets where each set is formed by points have the same x-coordinate
set_by_x = form_sets_by_x_coordinate(contour_points)
for set in set_by_x:
   if len(set) == 2:
       p = lower_point_in_set(set)
       lower_line_point_list.append(p)
clean_up(lower_line_point_list) #check for 4-connectivity
```